# What is the French verb for ”glitching” ?

Tags: traduction

This maybe an easy question but I still need help: I want to say in French “My phone is glitching.” But when I look on https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french nothing comes up.

Comment: If you consider that my phone is glitching means exactly the same thing as my phone [has a glitch](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/glitch) *Collins* gives you the answer. And there are other dictionaries you could have looked at, even a [good online translator](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/My%20phone%20is%20glitching).

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous : Oui absolument. Glitch est d'abord un substantif.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of expressions that are commonly used in France in such a situation:

> *Mon téléphone beugue.* (pronounced like "bug", from the verb [beuguer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beuguer) which has variants)
>
> *Mon téléphone déconne.* (Colloquial).

They are conveying the intended meaning of an ongoing, repetitive or sporadic issue which is how I understand *is glitching*. On the other hand, *my phone has a glitch* refers more to a single defect, something that doesn't work as intended.

Beware not to translate "to have a glitch" by *être en panne*. Being *en panne* means being out of order, unusable while having a glitch means working fine but having sometimes an odd behavior.

The formal/technical way to describe it is:

> *Mon téléphone<sup>1</sup> a un problème intermittent/inattendu, un comportement bizarre.*

<sup>1</sup><sub>Or *portable, mobile, GSM, Natel, cellulaire* depending on the French speaking country.</sub>

Comment: J'avais appris le substantif en situation chez les indigènes de la colonie. On va certes rester dans le lexique des petites bestioles désagréables mais Il signifiait très exactement *parasite* soulignant ainsi un coté nécessairement aléatoire / non reproductible. que *bug* ne portait pas. Donc oui et +1 forcément pour ton *déconner*... :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [French free encyclopedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch) (and this  [ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6nRrBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT201&dq=%22glitch%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2wbin8__lAhUPkxQKHUnzC6QQ6AEIkQIwHw#v=onepage&q=%22glitch%22&f=false)) you can say what follows if you know that the error comes from a program (for instance blurred 3D display).

- Il y a un glitch/bug/bogue dans mon téléphone.

If the problem is not known to you, that is if you don't know whether the hardware or the software is responsible, you can simply use the general forms that follow; they cover all aspects of malfunctionning, that due to the programmation and that due to the electronics/electrics and as well server problems. All listed possibilities  belong to the standard French language.

- Mon téléphone est détraqué. (*out of order or totally unusable*)
- Mon téléphone a une panne. (*remark as above*)
- Mon téléphone est en panne. (*rather totally unusable*)
- Mon téléphone marche/fonctionne mal. (*out of order*)
- Mon téléphone a un fonctionnement erratique. (*out of order*)